# Html.RenderAction Model passing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to rendering a partial view from _Layout.cshtml and getting error-

> 'Categories' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

```
@Html.RenderAction("_GuestNav", Categories);
```

How can i solve that error?

Picture attached for better understanding

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6xsY.png)

Comment: `@Html.RenderAction("_GuestNav", "ControllerName")`. If you using `RenderPartial`: `@Html.RenderPartial("_GuestNav", Categories)`

Comment: Thanks answer it